# How to replace multiple newlines for single one in whole file?

Tags: regular-expressions, text-editing

I have file which has multiple newlines. I want to receive single newline in their place.

I know how to do it in vim(found in google query):

```
:%s/\n\n\n*/\r\r/
```

How can I do the same in Emacs?

Example input:

```
this is file
with lines


and



empty lines 

badly
```

Example output:

```
this is file
with lines

and

empty lines 

badly
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `C-M-%` to run `query-replace-regexp`.  This works similarly to `query-replace` in db48x's answer, but allows for a regular expression.  Using

```
^
+
```

as input (^ matches end of line, followed by one or more newlines), and replace with a single newline.

Comment: To input a newline into the search/replace queries, hit `C-q C-j`

Comment: Can this run right after each save?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with this function:

```el
(defun remove-extra-blank-lines ()
    "replace multiple blank lines with a single one"
    (interactive)
    (setq orig (point))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "^\n+" nil t)
      (replace-match "\n")
      (forward-char 1))
     (goto-char orig))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Multiple empty lines are not replaced. The regexp "^\n+" works.

Comment: I just retested and it still works for me.

Comment: This works but changes the cursor position, would it be possible to prevent that, or just jump back to original cursor position?

Comment: @alper: I modified the function for your request.

Comment: Thanks I tried it inside a python file but seems like it did not mak any change :(

Comment: I changed the regular expression to that of user4035 (thanks!). It looks better.

Answer (score 2):

`M-%` runs the command `query-replace`, which prompts you first for the string to find, then the string to replace matches with. The enter key would normally close each of these prompts, so you have to do something special to search for or replace a newline.

Any time you want to type a character that would ordinarily have some other effect, you can prefix it with `C-q`. So `C-q RET` will enter the literal carriage return character, which is visually represented in a buffer as `^M`.

However, your text file may or may not use carriage returns to indicate newlines. Most likely it uses line feeds instead. In this case you'll want to use `C-q C-J` instead.

So, to put it all together: use `M-% C-q C-j C-q C-j RET C-q C-j RET` to replace two line-feed characters in a row with a single line-feed character.

At each match the `query-replace` command will ask you what to do. You can replace a single match, skip a match, or hit `!` to replace all matches. There are a few other options as well.

Comment: Isn't it better to use `^C-q C-j C-q C-j +`? Alos, `C-x h` to mark the whole buffer

Comment: Shouldn't your "put all together" command start with `M-%` instead of `C-%`?

Comment: @fredtantini: `query-replace` doesn't use regex matching

Comment: @db48x Indeed. That was for `C-M-%`…

Answer (score 1):

You could use `replace-regexp` (<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>) to replace at least two new lines, with just one. To enter a new line, you can use <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>. So:
<kbd>C-M-%</kbd> (or M-x replace-regexp) then you replace <kbd>^C-q C-j C-q C-j +</kbd> with <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>